# $.param serialized object to JSON

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, serialization

I send data from client to server (*Python*) using *$.fileDownload*. API receives the data but, as the *jQuery fileDownload docs* state, the *data is serialiazed using $.param*. The problem is that I need to have the data in *JSON format* so that I can handle it and create a file using it's *key:value pairs*. I've been trying to figure this out but nothing seems to be done in order to *"deserialize"* it. It also seems that I can't make *$.fileDownload to send data as a JSON object* in the first place. Is there any way that I turn the serialized data to JSON?

Here is my JavaScript request:

```
let data = {
  'name': item.Name,
  'rows': item.rows
}

window.$.fileDownload('/api/export-report-excel', {
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  encodeHTMLEntities: true,
  data: data
})
```

In my API I've tried json methods (json.dumps etc.) but the serialized object cannot be converted.

The *$.fileDownload* states:

> // data must be an object (which will be $.param serialized) or already a key=value param string

**EDIT:**

In my *Falcon API*:

```
@route('/api/export-report-excel')
class ExportReportToExcel(object):

  def on_post(self, req, resp):
    data = req.stream.read()
    log.info(data)
```

*log.info(data)* output:

> b'name=Priority+Rules&rows%5B0%5D%5BSegment%5D=HH+wo+TV&rows%5B0%5D%5BValue%5D=6&rows%5B0%5D%5BCampaignType%5D=CampaignType%3F&rows%5B0%5D%5BCampaignSubtype%5D=Predefined+Contract&rows%5B0%5D%5BChannel%5D=WIND+STORE&rows%5B0%5D%5BPriority%5D=1&rows%5B1%5D%5BSegment%5D=HH+wo+TV&rows%5B1%5D%5BValue%5D=6&rows%5B1%5D%5BCampaignType%5D=CampaignType%3F&rows%5B1%5D%5BCampaignSubtype%5D=Predefined+Contract&rows%5B1%5D%5BChannel%5D=SMART+WIND+STORE+MALL&rows%5B1%5D%5BPriority%5D=2'

Comment: You haven't really explained enough about what you are doing. What is handling this request? Your server is not just "Python", presumably it's running some kind of framework - which? You need to show the server-side code and what you tried to decode this parameters.

Comment: It's running falcon to handle the request. As I mentioned, I tried json.(methods) but  it doesn't work. The problem is that the data is serialized through $.param and then sent over the the server.

Comment: No that is not the problem. But you need to **show your Falcon code**. *What* did you try to pass to the json method? And do you actually need a JSON string, or a dict? What are you hoping to do with the data?

Comment: I tried both dumps and loads. I'm reading the data using req.stream.read(). That's what I tried to pass in dumps and loads. I didn't post my Falcon code because I keep changing it all the time, I can't manage to get the data to be converted in json.

Comment: @DanielRoseman posted what I get in my API. I tried to deserialize it with pickle but it didn't work. I can't find a way to convert it back to an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is form-encoded data, which you can parse in Python using `urllib.parse.parse_qs`.

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> parse.parse_qs('name=Priority+Rules&rows%5B0%5D%5BSegment%5D=HH+wo+TV&rows%5B0%5D%5BValue%5D=6&rows%5B0%5D%5BCampaignType%5D=CampaignType%3F&rows%5B0%5D%5BCampaignSubtype%5D=Predefined+Contract&rows%5B0%5D%5BChannel%5D=WIND+STORE&rows%5B0%5D%5BPriority%5D=1&rows%5B1%5D%5BSegment%5D=HH+wo+TV&rows%5B1%5D%5BValue%5D=6&rows%5B1%5D%5BCampaignType%5D=CampaignType%3F&rows%5B1%5D%5BCampaignSubtype%5D=Predefined+Contract&rows%5B1%5D%5BChannel%5D=SMART+WIND+STORE+MALL&rows%5B1%5D%5BPriority%5D=2')

{'name': ['Priority Rules'],
 'rows[0][Segment]': ['HH wo TV'],
 'rows[0][Value]': ['6'],
 'rows[0][CampaignType]': ['CampaignType?'],
 'rows[0][CampaignSubtype]': ['Predefined Contract'],
 'rows[0][Channel]': ['WIND STORE'],
 'rows[0][Priority]': ['1'],
 'rows[1][Segment]': ['HH wo TV'],
 'rows[1][Value]': ['6'],
 'rows[1][CampaignType]': ['CampaignType?'],
 'rows[1][CampaignSubtype]': ['Predefined Contract'],
 'rows[1][Channel]': ['SMART WIND STORE MALL'],
 'rows[1][Priority]': ['2']}
```

I don't know Falcon, but I am sure that it has a way of accessing this data directly, without accessing the raw stream or passing into `parse_qs`. In Django or Flask you would get it via `request.POST`, which is a dictionary; skimming through the Falcon docs, it looks like [`req.params`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.params) might do a similar job, although you may need to set the [`auto_parse_form_urlencoded`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html#falcon.RequestOptions.auto_parse_form_urlencoded) option to True first.